Using React.lazy with TypeScript and Vite
I encountered an error while lazily loading the React routing component
 Failed to resolve module specifier '@/pages/login/index' 

I have already configured aliases in vite and tsconfig
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';
const LayComponent: React.FC<any> = ({ pageName }) => {
 const LazyCom = React.lazy(() => import(/* @vite-ignore */ `@/pages/${pageName}/index`));
 const loadIngDom = <div>Loading....</div>;
 return (
  <Suspense fallback={loadIngDom}>
   <LazyCom></LazyCom>
  </Suspense>
 );
};
export default LayComponent;


This is an open issue in Vite's Github repo, probably arising from Rollup's limitation. And it has crept up to other web frameworks like Svelte too.
Basically, you cannot have path alias with variable names.
You can do
  const LazyCom = React.lazy(() =>
    import(/* @vite-ignore */ `./components/${pageName}/index`)
  );

or
  const LazyCom = React.lazy(() =>
    import(/* @vite-ignore */ `@components/test/index`)
  );

and both will work. But it seems that using both of them together will cause issues.
Here is a reproduction of the above code
This plugin claims to help, you can try it out.

Thank you for answering my question， const LazyCom = React.lazy(() =>     import(/* @vite-ignore */./components/${pageName}/index)   );  Will display

Sure. If it helped you please upvote/accept the answer to complete the question
